# the underlying provider failed on open not supported on new pc

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, dataprovider

I have an application with locale database. on my dev pc everything is alright, but when i try  to run my application on new pc i have exception and this message 'the underlying provider failed on open not supported'

I use EntityModel with this connectionString:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="KinesotherapyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Database.Kinesotherapy.csdl|res://*/Database.Kinesotherapy.ssdl|res://*/Database.Kinesotherapy.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database\kinesotherapy.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Have you installed the database on that computer too?

Comment: Wich connectionString?

Comment: i didn't install sql server on the other pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need include the Compact-Sql DLL's with your Application.

select the Compact-Sql reference in Solution Explorer then set `CopyLocal` Property to true.

see http://erikej.blogspot.co.il/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html